# Connecting to .NET webservice from android application

Tags: c#, android, web-services, signalr

I am trying to connect from android application with .NET webservice. I am using github.com/SignalR/java-client. I have almost no experience with Android and I cannot find solution to my problem. I tried to use these sample: github.com/SignalR/java-samples for implementing android client. In MainActivity.java I have method

```
public void buttonClick(View v)
    {
        HubConnection conn = new HubConnection("http://192.168.132.28:9000");

        // Create the hub proxy
        HubProxy proxy = conn.createHubProxy("HubClient");

        proxy.subscribe(new Object() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void messageReceived(String name, String message) {
                System.out.println(name + ": " + message);
            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the error event
        conn.error(new ErrorCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the connected event
        conn.connected(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("CONNECTED");
            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the closed event
        conn.closed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("DISCONNECTED");
            }
        });

        // Start the connection
        conn.start()
                .done(new Action<Void>() {

                    @Override
                    public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Done Connecting!");
                    }
                });

        // Subscribe to the received event
        conn.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(JsonElement json) {
                System.out.println("RAW received message: " + json.toString());
            }
        });

        // Read lines and send them as messages.
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = inputReader.nextLine();
        while (!"exit".equals(line)) {
            proxy.invoke("send", "Console", line).done(new Action<Void>() {

                @Override
                public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("SENT!");
                }
            });

            line = inputReader.next();
        }

        inputReader.close();

        conn.stop();
    }
```

This method is invoked when button is pressed. But when I press the button I get an exception `microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.NegotiationException: There was a problem in the negotiation with the server`
I use [this](https://github.com/SignalR/Samples/tree/master/Samples_2.1.0) webservice for testing. [Here](http://pastebin.com/jpcqdZnV) is full log from logcat (after pressing button). I disabled my firewall for testing. I tried to connect to server on my local computer and later on remote server. In both cases I have the same exception. I appreciate any suggestions.
This is Startup class in webservice:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using WebApplication.Features.Authorization;
using WebApplication.Features.SamplePersistentConnection;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WebApplication.Startup))]
namespace WebApplication
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
            app.MapSignalR<DemoPersistentConnection>("/Connections/DemoPersistentConnection");
            app.MapSignalR<AuthorizationPersistentConnection>("/Connections/AuthorizationPersistentConnection");

            app.Map("/EnableDetailedErrors", map =>
            {
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true
                };

                map.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is DemoHub class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace WebApplication.Features.SampleHub
{
    public class DemoHub : Hub
    {
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            return Clients.All.hubMessage("OnConnected " + Context.ConnectionId);
        }

        //public override Task OnDisconnected()
        //{
        //    return Clients.All.hubMessage("OnDisconnected " + Context.ConnectionId);
        //}

        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            return Clients.Caller.hubMessage("OnReconnected");
        }

        public void SendToMe(string value)
        {
            Clients.Caller.hubMessage(value);
        }

        public void SendToConnectionId(string connectionId, string value)
        {
            Clients.Client(connectionId).hubMessage(value);
        }

        public void SendToAll(string value)
        {
            Clients.All.hubMessage(value);
        }

        public void SendToGroup(string groupName, string value)
        {
            Clients.Group(groupName).hubMessage(value);
        }

        public void JoinGroup(string groupName, string connectionId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionId))
            {
                connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;    
            }

            Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName);
            Clients.All.hubMessage(connectionId + " joined group " + groupName);
        }

        public void LeaveGroup(string groupName, string connectionId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionId))
            {
                connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            }

            Groups.Remove(connectionId, groupName);
            Clients.All.hubMessage(connectionId + " left group " + groupName);
        }

        public void IncrementClientVariable()
        {
            Clients.Caller.counter = Clients.Caller.counter + 1;
            Clients.Caller.hubMessage("Incremented counter to " + Clients.Caller.counter);
        }

        public void ThrowOnVoidMethod()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ThrowOnVoidMethod");
        }

        public async Task ThrowOnTaskMethod()
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ThrowOnTaskMethod");
        }

        public void ThrowHubException()
        {
            throw new HubException("ThrowHubException", new { Detail = "I can provide additional error information here!" });
        }

        public void StartBackgroundThread()
        {
            BackgroundThread.Enabled = true;
            BackgroundThread.SendOnPersistentConnection();
            BackgroundThread.SendOnHub();
        }

        public void StopBackgroundThread()
        {
            BackgroundThread.Enabled = false;            
        }
    }
```

P.S. I apologize for not using https in links to github, but new users are only allowed to create 2 links.

Comment: Can you provide your Server side code ?

Comment: Also provide your startup class

Comment: I edited my post. Previously link to webservice was wrong (It was link to project which I tried to use earlier). I hope you can download the code from there. I also included Startup class here.

Comment: Please provide me the code of hub class i think i got your problem.

Comment: When I looked at ConsoleClient in C# for this webservice I realized that in method connection.CreateHubProxy() argument is the name of Hub defined in webserice project (in this case DemoHub). Is this true in general? I try to change that in my adnroid code but I still have the same error.